# how do i align my navbar brand to the center and have my nav links surround it from both sides

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want my navbar brand to be in the middle and my nav links to be positioned on the left and right of my nav brand. Because when the screen reaches md I want the nav links to disappear and be in the burger but still have my nav brand showing at the top center.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark py-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand"><h2>Name</h2></div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#burger"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="burger">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item px-5">
                        <a href="#python" class="nav-link" style="color: white;"><h2>Python</h2></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-5">
                        <a href="#html&css" class="nav-link" style="color: white;"><h2>Html&Css</h2></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I am going for this look
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBR3P.png)

Answer (score 0):

## HTML

```html
<h1 class="text-center">Center Navbar Brand logo</h1>


<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://disputebills.com"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTvuVbC_1kQQsg8U63u6gWMWuA7W1Ck5t-zkw&usqp=CAU" alt="logo">
      </a>
      </div>
      

      
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

## CSS

```css
.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}


/* DEMO example styles for logo image */
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 7px 14px;
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]